# how to display content from mysql database on a html page from bottom to top

Tags: html, mysql

I want my page to load results in reverse; starting from bottom to top of page like in Facebook messenger, when scroll it load more result on top of each orther.

click for more result
(page with 3rd sets of results after click for more result)
     result 1
     result 2
     result 3
     result 4
     result 5
     result 6
     result 7
     result 8
     result 9

click for more result
(page with 2nd set of result after click for more results)
     result 4
     result 5
     result 6
     result 7
     result 8
     result 9

click for more results
(page load with first set of results)
     result 7
     result 8
     result 9

Currently I have the below

click for more result
(page with 2nd set of result after click for more results)
     result 4
     result 5
     result 6
     result 7
     result 8
     result 9

click for more result
(page with 3rd sets of results after click for more result)
     result 1
     result 2
     result 3
     result 4
     result 5
     result 6
     result 7
     result 8
     result 9

click for more results
(page load with first set of results)
     result 7
     result 8
     result 9

Comment: Just get your sql results in a reverse order with `DESC`. For example `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY some_column DESC`

Comment: Done that already, i need when adding to html page it don't go below existing result, want result aboveit to go on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what a want using Jquery .prepend() getting to load each result before each other.